# Sorting, filtering, and paging at DB side using LINQ to Entities without hand-written SQL

Tags: linq, entity-framework

To minimize the data transferred from SQL server to app server (IIS), I wonder whether people do sorting, filtering, and paging using pure LINQ to Entites.
By "pure LINQ" I mean no hand-written SQL statements or views/stored procedures.

I found some articles helpful, for example:

- [Entity Framework: How to Increase Performance with Paging](https://www.talksharp.com/entity-framework-paging)
- [Sorting, Filtering, and Paging with the Entity Framework in an ASP.NET MVC Application](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/sorting-filtering-and-paging-with-the-entity-framework-in-an-asp-net-mvc-application)

But they didn't cover all features I need, so I'm writing my own helper classes for the following requirements:

- multiple columns sorting
- multiple columns filtering (support various joint operators such as AND/OR, and comparing operators such as equals, contains, larger than, smaller than..., etc.
- paging

As mentioned, I'd like them to be done with "pure" LINQ to Entities and executed at database side. Is that a good idea or do you suggest using stored procedures?

Much appreciated if any suggestion or code sample.

Comment: when you are writing linq and sending it back to sql and returning the result its optimized, as you are retuning only results (Iqueriable) check the queries being executed on sql using sql profiler. If you are using to list first and then implementing where or some filter clause, than its returning all the results to code and them implementing filter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Entity Framework without storage procedures and, with a little attention, you can be compatible with most important databases.
For multiple column sorting you can use

```
OrderBy(x => x.a).ThenBy(x => x.b)...
```

For joins you can navigate the tree model (in query, otherwise you activate a lazy load).
Paging are

```
Skip/Take
```

You can use boolean expression for test multiple condition in the same Where statement

```
context.Persons.Where(p => p.Name == "me" && p.Age == 15)
```

and also add different where statement.

```
tbl.Where(...).Where(...)
```

The 2 condition in the query are inserted with AND

I do not use stored procedure because of compatibility with different DBMSs but several people does.

Comment: Since this is the only answer, I've just finished my first version of dynamic sorting, filtering and paging at DB side using LINQ to Entities, I'll mark it as then answer. Thank you!
By the way, this article helped me a lot: [Build Where Clause Dynamically in Linq](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/582450/Build-Where-Clause-Dynamically-in-Linq)